Is exists elegant solution to automatically change the space if `\dfrac` appeared in inline equation?
The \dfrac is appeared in inline equation is not so elegant in inline text. I want to adjust the space here.
To be detailed, I want the Length 1 is the same as Length2 if \dfrac appeared in inline equation.

As shown below, although I know the requirement is a little unreasonable, for which I should use a/b instead of \verb|\dfrac|, but I just curious about that if it exists elegant solution of adjusting the spaces.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\begin{document}
    I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it$\frac{1}{2}$ does not hurt$\dfrac{1}{3}$ me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me. I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can$\frac{1}{2}$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does$\dfrac{1}{3}$ not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.

    I wonder that is there any solution to adjust the linespread if \verb|\dfrac| appeared in inline equation and it can automatically so that the space "between top of the fraction and last line" and "the bottom of the fraction and next line" is as equal as the normal text like \verb|\lipsum|.

    \lipsum[1]

    Although I know the requirement is unreasonable, for which I should use a/b instead of \verb|\dfrac|, but I just curious about that if it exists elegant solution of adjusting the spaces.
    
    \end{document}

Thanks to cfr, my requirement of the length is not clear with the baseline of the letters, and what I mean, is just to modify the \linespread to be 1.5 if there exists the \dfrac in the text.
Thanks for your patience and kindness.

an easy way to illustrate my requirement, that is, insert a phantom box before and after the tex line with \dfrac:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\begin{document}
    I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.

    I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.

    I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.

    I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.

    I can eat glass, it$\frac{1}{2}$ does not hurt$\dfrac{1}{3}$ me.

    I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.

    I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.

    I can$\frac{1}{2}$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.

    I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.\phantom{$\dfrac{1}{3}$}

    I can eat glass, it does$\dfrac{1}{3}$ not hurt me.\phantom{$\dfrac{1}{3}$}

    I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.\phantom{$\dfrac{1}{3}$}
    \end{document}



I know that tabularray can adjust the \dfrac case in tblr automatically, is that provides thoughts?

you really do not want to parse your entire document using the methods applied by tabularray. it slows compilation significantly. that's one thing for a table. it would be quite another to do it for the entire body of text.

your arrows are not comparing like with like. the distance from baseline to g will obviously be greater than that to l because the latter is taller than the former. but, also, why would you use \dfrac in the middle of text? is there a use case for this?

I know the usage of \dfrac in the middle of text is not recommended, but there exists some opinion that the Numerator and Denominator to be the same size as the normal text, which maybe is the use case, the \frac in inline equation actually a liitle not so harmanious.

Yep, you said that your arrows are not comparing like with like and the baseline is correct, my requirement is not so specific, I will change the question to what I want to achieve is to change the \linespread{1.5} is there exists the \dfrac in text. Is that easy to achieve, althouth the \linespread in one paragraph shouldn't change frenquently, but as I mentioned in the question, I just curious about that.

as far as I can tell, the spacing is already the same as between e.g. p and I or whatever. however, some digits protrude slightly below the baseline and/or the X height. 3 is one of those (in this font). but 4, say, is not. that is, of course, different from wanting to change the linespread to 1.5.

You wrote, "but there exists some opinion that the Numerator and Denominator to be the same size as the normal text." IMNSHO, it's a non-sequitur to conclude that \dfrac is the appropriate solution for inline-math situations. A second solution is to switch to inline-fraction notation, i.e., to replace \[d]frac{1}{2} with 1/2. I'm not sure I understand what you wrote in the final paragraph, but you appear to be claiming that switching from \frac notation to inline-fraction notation is an "unreasonable requirement"? What's so unreasonable about this?

@Mico I don't say 1/2 is not good. Actually, according the math equation typeset convention: we use use 1/2 instead of \dfrac{1}{2}. I know that 1/2 is better solution to typeset fraction inline. However, if I want to change the linespread (opposed to the convention, and destory the unique linespread in the same paragraph),  I wonder is that elegant method to make the line with \dfrac looks looser as the same text.

The Better Practice to typeset in text inline is 1/2, which make the uniform(I mean the paragraph spacing is the same) spacing; However, we can trade off between them: just with \dfrac, it protrude to the next line; and I want to set a higher linespread. What I mean unreasonable is the latter one is not recommendated, and it may cause the linespread of one paragraph to be 1.0,1.5,1.0,1.5.... In my opinion, that is inconsistent. I hopes I make it clearly.

I think I found an easy way to illustrate my requirement, that is, insert a phantom box before and after the tex line with \dfrac.(appended to the original question finnally)

@Explorer adding the phantoms is surely not an answer to anything, you would have to do it on every line of the paragraph and it makes no sense to do that why not just set the baselineskip for the paragraph?

If you have a document where you are choosing to use ``\dfracinline (despite the command name and documentation explicitly saying it is not for that use) then simply set\baselinestretch` globally for the document so that all lines have a spacing that will take a fraction of that size.

One of the essential and non-negotiable aspects of fine typography is having "even color" or, more exactly, "even average grayness", across paragraphs. Switching the value of \linespread from one paragraph to another by a nontrivial amount makes achieving the "even average grayness" goal pretty much impossible.
The following screenshot contains six paragraphs to illustrate the effects of varying the line-spacing amounts. At the end of each paragraph, the value of \baselineskip is shown in red.

The first two paragraphs employ inline-fraction notation and \frac notation, respectively, while single-spacing is in effect. Observe that these paragraphs do just fine in terms of both consistent overall grayness and evenness of line-spacing.

The third paragraph uses \dfrac instead of \frac, along with single-spacing. This change causes the line spacing to be hopelessly uneven.

The fourth paragraph also employs \dfrac but now executes \setstretch{1.5}. Note that the line spacing is still not entirely uniform.

The fifth paragraph uses \dfrac notation but runs \doublespacing, which is equivalent to running \setstretch{1.667}. Only now is the line spacing even within the paragraph.

The sixth and final paragraph repeats the first one, i.e., \singlespacing is in effect along with the use of inline-fraction notation. I hope you will agree that "even color" is nowhere to be found in the juxtaposition of paragraphs 5 and 6.



What's the upshot? If even color across paragraphs is a goal for you (and it should be!), don't let \linespread vary across paragraphs. Unless you're willing to employ \doublespacing or something even worse, such as \setstretch{2}, this constraint implies that using \dfrac within a text paragraph is an absolute no-no. It also follows that switching from \frac notation to inline-fraction notation to typeset fractions within a text paragraph may be a rather desirable thing to do from a typographic point of view.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,setspace,xcolor}
\addtolength\textheight{3\baselineskip} % just for this example

\newcommand{\Iceg}{I can eat glass, it does not hurt me}
\newcommand\blurbA{% use inline-fraction notation
\Iceg.\Iceg.\Iceg.\Iceg.I can eat glass, it $1/2$ does not hurt $1/3$ me.\Iceg.\Iceg.I can $1/2$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.\Iceg.I can eat glass, it does $1/3$ not hurt me.\Iceg.\ \textcolor{red}{\the\baselineskip}}
\newcommand\blurbB{% use '\frac' notation
\Iceg.\Iceg.\Iceg.\Iceg.I can eat glass, it $\frac{1}{2}$ does not hurt $\frac{1}{3}$ me.\Iceg.\Iceg.I can $\frac{1}{2}$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.\Iceg.I can eat glass, it does $\frac{1}{3}$ not hurt me.\Iceg.\ \textcolor{red}{\the\baselineskip}}
\newcommand\blurbC{% use '\dfrac' notation
\Iceg.\Iceg.\Iceg.\Iceg.I can eat glass, it $\dfrac{1}{2}$ does not hurt $\dfrac{1}{3}$ me.\Iceg.\Iceg.I can $\dfrac{1}{2}$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.\Iceg.I can eat glass, it does $\dfrac{1}{3}$ not hurt me.\Iceg.\ \textcolor{red}{\the\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\blurbA

\medskip

\blurbB

\bigskip

\blurbC
    
\medskip

{\setstretch{1.5} 
\blurbC\par}

\medskip

{\doublespacing % equivalent to '\setstretch{1.667}'
\blurbC\par}

\medskip % back to singlespacing

\blurbA
    
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,setspace,xcolor}
\addtolength\textheight{3\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it $1/2$ does not hurt $1/3$ me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can $1/2$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does $1/3$ not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me. \textcolor{red}{\the\baselineskip}

\medskip

I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it $\frac{1}{2}$ does not hurt $\frac{1}{3}$ me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can $\frac{1}{2}$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does $\frac{1}{3}$ not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me. \textcolor{red}{\the\baselineskip}

\bigskip

I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it $\dfrac{1}{2}$ does not hurt $\dfrac{1}{3}$ me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can $\dfrac{1}{2}$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does $\dfrac{1}{3}$ not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me. \textcolor{red}{\the\baselineskip}
    
\medskip

{%
\setstretch{1.5} 
I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it $\dfrac{1}{2}$ does not hurt $\dfrac{1}{3}$ me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can $\dfrac{1}{2}$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does $\dfrac{1}{3}$ not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me. \textcolor{red}{\the\baselineskip}\par}

\medskip

{%
\doublespacing % equivalent to '\setstretch{1.667}'
I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it $\dfrac{1}{2}$ does not hurt $\dfrac{1}{3}$ me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can $\dfrac{1}{2}$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does $\dfrac{1}{3}$ not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me. \textcolor{red}{\the\baselineskip}\par}

\medskip
I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it $1/2$ does not hurt $1/3$ me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can $1/2$ eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does $1/3$ not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me. \textcolor{red}{\the\baselineskip}
    
\end{document}


I can'r aggre u more than that inline-fraction notation is the recommended solution now, very grateful to u!
